# Limiting the Selection by Color to a Specific Area of an Image in Gimp

Tags: gimp, transparency, selections

[image] On this image, I'm trying to make the name in black letters transperent

I have this image in Gimp where I need to select a specific color (namely the name circled in blue) to make transparent; however, I would like to limit the selection to just a portion of the image. So far I have been able to make everything in black transparent, but not just the name. Is there any way to limit the range? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you could post an image to show what you are trying to achieve.  There might be a way of achieving it that is completely different from what you have tried so far.

Comment: I added a picture above to make in more clear what I am hoping to do. I have other images I plan to work on with similar problems where I just need a portion of the image's color to be transparent, so a basic guideline on to approach this problem would be helpful.

Comment: What tool have you been trying to use to make the selection? Have you tried using the Fuzzy Select tool, while holding down Shift to make a multiple selection of the letters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Method 1

- Make a selection for the area of interest using whatever selection tool (free hand, ellipse, rectangle, path...)
- `Select>Save to channel`
- Select you layer again (the previous operation makes the saved channel the active drawable)
- Use the Color Selector to make your color selection
- open the Channels list, right-click the saved selection, and `Intersect with selection`

A variant is to start with the color selection, save it to a channel, do the area selection, and intersect with the saved selection.

### Method 2

- Make a selection for area of interest using whatever selection tool (free hand, ellipse, rectangle, path...)
- Copy that selection to a new layer (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-Shift-N)
- Make you color selection on that new layer
- Delete that temporary layer
- Activate the initial layer and use the selection

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Then you can "accept" the answer, this flags it for other users.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple method

- Select the region of interest using your prefered selection tool (eg rectangle or ellipse)
- Choose the `Select by Color Tool`
- Change the mode of the tool to `Intersect with the current selection` (4th in row) or just hold down `Shift + Ctrl`
- Click on the color your want to select

#### Note

Sometimes, when the area you want to select has heterogeneous color it's easier to select region and subtract everything unwanted with the `Select by Color Tool` while holding `Ctrl`.
If you have subtracted too much you can add desired with the `Fuzzy Select Tool` while holding `Shift`.